# Major Justice League continuity error?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, justice-league

Within *Justice League*, SteppenWolf confirms that Cyborg was created by the third Motherbox, when he states to Cyborg that **'You were born of her'**. This confirms it was definitely *the* Motherbox Steppenwolf is looking for/referring to.

Later, at the Batcave, Cyborg tells the League about his creation/resurrection via the Motherbox.

> Cyborg: It was found by the British during WW1. They studied it but...
>   they couldn't even date it, it was so old. **It was shelved... until
>   the night Superman died.** Then she lit up like Christmas. They
>   brought it to STAR labs where my father recognised it as a perpetual
>   energy matrix. [...] A Motherbox destroys as it creates. It's a cycle
>   of life, but a million times faster. My father thought it was the key
>   to unlimited energy; new formulas, cellular regeneration... but it's
>   too volatile, to hard to control.
>
> Bruce:...He used it on you.

The above is verbatim... and makes absolutely no sense, regarding the continuity of the current continuity. We know for a fact that Silas Stone created Cyborg Waaaaaaay before Superman died, because during the events of *Batman Vs. Superman* Bruce watches archive footage of his creation, and Zach Snyder has confirmed the above;

> That’s the first glimpse of the Mother Box there. It was an agonizing birth.

[image]

You can see the Motherbox (all 'lit up like Christmas') in the above picture, with Cyborg in the background. This is archive footage stolen from Luthor; we know it's prior to Superman's death, but it could be quite a while before it.

How do we rationalise Cyborg's claim, and indeed the entire 'Superman's death caused the Motherbox to activate and become beacons for Steppenwolf' element of the plot;

### ...Given that we can demonstrate the Boxes were already active well before his death?

Comment: @NapoleonWIlson, Wow. My autocorrect sure did a number on that poor 'cyclops' character, ha ha!

Answer (score 3):

Well that is a major continuity error. The possible reason behind this could be the reshoots, post production problems,etc. that may have caused a lapse in checking all continuity or other types of mistakes.

Maybe that is due to a possible relation to future movies like Flashpoint, but it is highly unlikely.

As everyone knows, this movie is riddled with plot holes, continuity errors and factual errors.
[Check here on IMDb for all the errors and goofs](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0974015/goofs)